# How to plot normal vectors in each point of the curve with a given length?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, geometry

How to plot normal vectors in each point of the curve with a given length?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
ax.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.06)
ax.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot the `normals`, you need to calculate the slope at each point; from there, you get the tangent vector that you can rotate by `pi/2`.

[image]

here is one approach using python i/o np, which makes it probably easier to understand at first.

Changing the length will adjust the size of the normals to properly scale with your plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def get_normals(length=.1):
    
    for idx in range(len(x)-1):
        x0, y0, xa, ya = x[idx], y[idx], x[idx+1], y[idx+1]
        dx, dy = xa-x0, ya-y0
        norm = math.hypot(dx, dy) * 1/length
        dx /= norm
        dy /= norm
        
        ax.plot((x0, x0-dy), (y0, y0+dx))    # plot the normals


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2
ax.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.06)
ax.plot(x, y)
get_normals()


plt.show()
```

or longer normals, directed downwards: `get_normals(length=-.3)`
(use `ax.set_aspect('equal')` to maintain angles)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8, 8]

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = x**2

# Calculating the gradient
L=.1 # gradient length
grad = np.ones(shape = (2, x.shape[0]))
grad[0, :] = -2*x
grad /= np.linalg.norm(grad, axis=0)  # normalizing to unit vector

nx = np.vstack((x - L/2 * grad[0], x + L/2 * grad[0]))
ny = np.vstack((y - L/2 * grad[1], y + L/2 * grad[1]))

# ax.set_ylim(-0.3, 1.06)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.plot(nx, ny, 'r')
ax.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image]